# extraction of required columns from many files and writing it to a single file

Tags: perl

```
perl -F"\t" -lane '$, = ","; print $F[0], $F[4]' EM2.gcount > Em2gcount.csv
```

Using this command I was able to extract 0 and 4 column from file 1 and wrote in the separate file in .csv...I have many files and also I want to print them in to single file...
please help me what changes should i make

Comment: Use `>>` instead of `>` to append to a _single file_.

Comment: `perl -F"\t" -lane '...' infile1 infile2 infile3 >> outfile`

Comment: I tried to edit it but i am strucket at loops

Comment: devnull@ thers nothing >> like this

Comment: already answered http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1077090

Comment: Using `$,` to save yourself the trouble of typing one comma is excessive: `'print "$F[0],$F[4]"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find -type f -name "*.gcount" -exec <yourperlcommand> {} >> Em2gcount.csv \;`

this will find all .gcount files from your current directory and execute the perl command on `{}` which references the file found and appends it to Em2gcount.csv

Comment: That will invoke the Perl interpreter for every single file. `find -type f -name '*.gcount' -print0 | perl -n0e '...'` is better since it only invokes `perl` once (assuming `find` is even necessary; the OP hasn't indicated that they need to run this for files in subdirectories).

Comment: I also want to print the columns